# How to call a cell value from child sheet in laravel excel maatwebsite?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

```
$cellValue=$event->sheet->getSheet('SiteWork')->getCellByColumnAndRow(E, 4)->getValue();
dd($cellValue);
```

I am getting this error

> BadMethodCallException Method Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet::getSheet does
>   not exist.

Comment: `$event->getSheet()->getDelegate()->getParent()->getSheetByName('SiteWork')`

Answer (score 1):

I checked in the docs and I don't see any getSheet function.

This is the page I ended chosing:

> https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html

I have found a line that can be important in your way you are coding:

```
$import = new UsersImport();
$import->onlySheets('Worksheet 1', 'Worksheet 3');

Excel::import($import, 'users.xlsx');
```

But with your clarification I don't know if your code is from the controller or in a import class.

***EDIT:*** (Please clarify more the next time)

For Exports I have found this:

> https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/multiple-sheets.html

You need to use an extra class

Comment: I am working in  Export

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that, see my edit in a minute ;)

Comment: my code is from export controller